# How does one add mult rows at once to Excel via an Add In?

Tags: javascript, office-js, excel-addins

I am attempting to add multiple rows of data under the header.  This will be to a new table.  All of this runs on the same event handler.

Currently, the table *does* get created, and the header and header values do, too.  However, the rows of data will not load.

Here's the code I've got to create the table and populate the header and rows:

```
function createTable() {
  Excel.run(function (context) {

    const currentWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    const expensesTable = currentWorksheet.tables.add("A1:D1", true /*hasHeaders*/);
    expensesTable.name = "ExpensesTable";

    expensesTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = 
       [["Date", "Merchant", "Category", "Amount"]];

    expensesTable.rows.add(null /*add at the end*/, [
       ["1/1/2017", "The Phone Company", "Communications", "120"],
       ["1/2/2017", "Northwind Electric Cars", "Transportation", "142.33"],
       ["1/5/2017", "Best For You Organics Company", "Groceries", "27.9"],
       ["1/10/2017", "Coho Vineyard", "Restaurant", "33"],
       ["1/11/2017", "Bellows College", "Education", "350.1"],
       ["1/15/2017", "Trey Research", "Other", "135"],
       ["1/15/2017", "Best For You Organics Company", "Groceries", "97.88"]
    ]);

    expensesTable.columns.getItemAt(3).getRange().numberFormat = [['€#,##0.00']];
    expensesTable.getRange().format.autofitColumns();
    expensesTable.getRange().format.autofitRows();

    return context.sync();
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
  });
}
```

This will produce this error:

```
Error: InvalidArgument: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.

Debug info: {
  "code":"InvalidArgument",
  "message":"The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.",
  "errorLocation":"TableRowCollection.add"
}
```

I have been reading [the JS API docs](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/tablerowcollection) about the tableRowCollection Object and its add method, but I don't see what I am doing wrong here.  Any help would be WONDERFUL!

Comment: I would first try with -1 instead of null and adding a single row. (Debugging steps.)

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thanks Andy.  I have tried that and it does work for inserting one row at a time (both with null and -1).  Perhaps I should better ask, how could I go about entering in a larger amount of rows/data?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this at all. Your code is running fine for me. Could you provide the version of Excel you are using? Could you also add how your referencing the `office.js`?

Comment: Woops, sorry about that @MarcLaFleur - I just removed the office.js tag.  Didn't mean to include that.  I have Microsoft Office Pro Plus 2016 installed.  The Excel version is 2016 MSO (16.0.4591.1000) 32-bit.  Feel free to check out the full Add In code at [this repo](https://github.com/Zeeroh0/ExcelAddIn).  That project is pulled directly from [Microsoft's Excel Add In tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial-create-table).

Comment: You had the proper tag, this is an `office.js` add-in (a.k.a Office Web Add-in). :)

Comment: Hey @MarcLaFleur, I think I misunderstood you earlier. When you asked about my reference to `office.js`, did you mean the Office API? This is the script tag in the head of my index.html file `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments above, I realized that I wasn't getting access to the API's versions above 1.1.  This was due to having an old build of Excel.  I updated Excel and am now running a current version of 16.0, build 8730.2046.

[image]

See [this page for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets) on what API version is available to what Excel build.